# Selecting NULL values from two joined tables - not returning correct results (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, right-join

I use MySQL.

I have three tables:

Book, Publisher, Description.

In those tables I have **2** books, **3** publishers and **1** description from publisher **#1**

Description contains three fields **book_id**, **publisher_id**, **description**

I would like to select all records where description has been provided by the publisher or NULLs otherwise (if description was not provided by the publisher);

In other words I need the following output:

| book_id | publisher_id | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | blah |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | NULL |
| 2 | 3 | NULL |

Below is SQL I’m using:

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `publisher` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `description` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `book` (`id`) VALUES (1), (2);
INSERT INTO `publisher` (`id`) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO `description` (`book_id`, `publisher_id`, `description`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'blah');
```

The SQL I'm using looks like this but it doesn't return the results I need:

```
SELECT b.id book_id, p.id publisher_id, d.description FROM description d 
RIGHT JOIN book b ON d.book_id=b.id
RIGHT JOIN publisher p ON publisher_id=p.id
```

Your help will be greatly appriciated

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `cross join` between books and publishers and then to `left join` the description:

```
SELECT b.id book_id, p.id as publisher_id, d.description
FROM book b CROSS JOIN
     publisher p LEFT JOIN
     description d 
     ON d.book_id = b.id AND d.publisher_id = p.id
ORDER BY b.id, p.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=251c732a938fa5b6bb5469b1348a0d8f) is a db<>fiddle.